# Auto Refresh in Swing (Jtable)

Tags: java

I wrote a code which is get text from text area and save to file after that get data from file and show at jtable but I want to do that automatically when I add a new text to file it should be automatically show at the jtable does any one can help me?

```
try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File ("Member.txt")));


                    Object [] row = {id, firstname, lastname, age};

                    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();



                    Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

                    for(int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++)
                    {
                        String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                        String[] dataRow = line.split(" ");
                        dtm.addRow(dataRow);
                    }


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
```

this code help me to show data from file at jtable.

Comment: Your question is pretty broad, but I think my answer can guide you through the necessary steps to get to a solution. But please understand that turning my ideas into a working program is a bit of a challenge.  Please avoid asking "can you give the code?" ... this is your problem/assignment/work request ... so you are the one who needs to sit down, probably for many hours to implement a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your starting point is: using a [watch service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to determine when that file changed on disk.

Then you have to read the whole file and figure what changed (for example by keeping a "copy" of all lines of the file in memory).

Then you extract the newly added lines and add them to your table model.

Comment: I am not use any database :(

Comment: @IsmayilHakhverdiyev *Nothing* in my answer needs a database. You asked: how can I update my GUI when a **file** changes. And I just explained to you what you need to solve that problem.